Jenkins Pipeline not creating workspace directory
This is a "why is it doing this" question and looking for an explanation. I have a Jenkins pipeline maintenance job that is a delegate for other jobs which should then copy back to the delegate their results in text files.
The jobs that the delegate is calling are failing because the cp command is saying that the target directory does not exist. I looked and yes it doesn't exist.
My solution was to echo "hello, world" > txt.txt and now the delegate directory exists. So my question is, why isn't Jenkins creating the workspace for the job. I use delegates all over the place and they seem to work fine. The only real difference I can tell is that the agent for this specific delegate is "built-in" instead of a node. To answer why I am doing built-in, it's because the maintenance task has to run on both the master and the nodes.
Any help will be appreciated.

Jenkins does not automatically create a workspace directory for a pipeline job until the job explicitly performs an action that requires the workspace, such as checking out code or creating files. This is expected behavior for jobs running on the "built-in" agent (the Jenkins controller) or any agent.
Here's an example of how you can add an Execute Shell step in Jenkins Pipeline to perform a simple action: print the workspace environment variable and list all files in the workspace:


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Prepare Workspace') {
            steps {
                // Execute a shell command to print the workspace and list files
                sh '''
                echo "Workspace Directory: ${WORKSPACE}"
                ls -la ${WORKSPACE}
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}




As I stated in my post, I already figured out how to do it. And that wasn't the point. I wanted to know why. Thanks.

Why create a workspace if none is needed? Until a step action requires one, it won't do so. Why waste resources?
